# puppeteer nested list returning as txt

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, nested-loops

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('https://wordscapes.yourdictionary.com/');

const allItemsInPage = await page.$$(".item");
for (const item of allItemsInPage) {
  const url = await item.getProperty('href');

  const spanHandle = await item.$('.card');
  const textHandle = await spanHandle.getProperty('innerText');
  const text = await textHandle.jsonValue();

  console.log(`${url}`);
  console.log(`${text}`);
}
```

**allItemsInPage**
Contains Cards in each card has nested list.
What I expected Output: [Go and run the code then check the console](https://jsfiddle.net/2moab493/)

Comment: Why not put the expected output in the question itself rather than the fiddle? Links rot over time, making the question less useful to future visitors with the same problem as you. Right now, you're using `console.log` so I don't see any attempt at putting the results into a data structure.